# Multithreading in C++, only check if semaphore is locked

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mutex, semaphore

I am trying to solve a problem I am having on windows, using c++.

Let's say I have thread **A B C**, and thread **Z**.
A B C and Z are all sending data to an application via socket. But when Z is transferring data, I want A B and C to wait for Z to finish, then resume.

**A B C** can send data to application **concurrently**.

I am trying to use mutex to prevent A B C from running when Z is running, but I am finding that even when Z is not running, A B C are not running concurrently because of that mutex.

So my question ultimately is, is there a method in C++ that would allow me to check if mutex is locked, and if it is locked, wait for mutex to become unlocked, but **DO NOT** lock the mutex?

I never want A, B, and C to lock the mutex. Only Z should lock the mutex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a type of lock called a ["readers-writer lock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) that may solve your problem. It is intended for an object where there can be multiple concurrent readers but only one writer at a time (and the writer locks out the readers). It sounds very similar to your application, where A, B, and C are considered readers and Z is considered a writer.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Slim Reader/Writer locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx) - just what the doctor ordered.  Just have thread A, B, and C take read locks when working, and have thread Z take a write lock when it is working.